# Configure Self hosted Web Api in Windows Service to Use SSL by Calling from XMLHTTPREQUEST

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, https, owin

I have configured the Self hosted web api in windows service using SSL by calling it from XMLHTTPREQUEST(html page).

I am creating the self signed SSL certificate in the code itself by using CERTENROLLLib.dll.

Certificate is creating and also it's getting added to browser's Trusted Root Certification Authorities(In Browser's SSL Certificate list).

And also I have used CORS, http/https are working fine in IE.

Only Http is woking in the chrome but https is not working in the chrome - Directly it's going to onerror(function) and showing alert message.

I am not getting where is the problem - It's in web api or html page.
Here is my html function.

```
function COMPortOpen() {
            var url = "https://localhost:8989/Values/COMPortOpen";
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    if (xmlhttp.responseText == '"0"') {
                        alert("Device successfully connected");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Device not connected");
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
                    alert("Check If Service/Utility is Running");
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

What am I missing? How can I make Chrome to work with SSL Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried allowing CORS in chrome browser?

For Windows, run this in chrome directory from commandline 
(after closing all running chrome instances):

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Or, you might want to install a a plugin for chrome, to toggle CORS on/off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. I got solution.